# How to search arrays for values in Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Assuming we have an entity in Google Cloud Datastore - "Job" and it has some Access Control Tags:

```
["admin", "manager"]
```

and we have a user that has some Access Control Tags

```
["admin", "super_user"]
```

We would like to pull back all Jobs that this user has access to; e.g. in SQL something like

```
SELECT * from Job where tags INCLUDE "admin" OR tags INCLUDE "super_user"
```

OR queries are not supported, is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: entity in GCS?  what query syntax is that ?

Comment: Google Cloud Datastore sorry

Comment: select * from Job where tags = 'admin' or tags = 'super_user'

Comment: OR operators are not supported on google cloud datastore..

Answer (score 0):

Could you query the datastore model using ndb.OR? Something like in [this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/ndb/queries/snippets.py):

```
query = Article.query(ndb.AND(Article.tags == 'python',
                          ndb.OR(Article.tags.IN(['ruby', 'jruby']),
                                 ndb.AND(Article.tags == 'php',
                                         Article.tags != 'perl'))))
```

Comment: I see support for this in the AppEngine version of the Datastore documentation, but not the Google Cloud Datastore/google-cloud-* APIs. Wonder what is the reason. Is it perhaps the AppEngine version of the APIs running multiple queries for the OR condition?

Comment: Unfortunately we're not using the python library - also I suspect that this ndb.OR operation is performing application level querying as Datastore does not natively support OR-ing.

Answer (score 0):

You can query to retrieve multiple values like the following:

If you have array of multiple datastore Id's like following:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

You can query with gstore-node Package

```
var userData = await UserModel.get([1,2,3,4]);
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to store the data in array format in google cloud datastore. in here we can't use OR condition. so you can use > and < for equlity and also you can use the add_filter for that